# ILImageSCPlot always timeout

Tags: ilnumerics

In an Imageplot always Timeout is printed. Example:

```
 data = ILSpecialData.waterfallf(25, 100); 
 var ilmsc = new ILImageSCPlot(data);                                         
 var ilp = new ILPlotCube { ilmsc };
 ilPanel1.Scene.Add(new ILScene { ilp } );
```

If I have more data sometimes some missing. I want show spectrum intensity plot  (25-50 frequencies, every second for a hour or more).

The Timeout Property of ILPlotCube is 0 (no timeout). Driver ist set to OpenGL. GDI shows nothing, the other values can not configured. Stystem has Intel HD Graphics 2000 with 2560x1440.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add a scene to a scene. If you remove the additional scene the "timeout" label will vanish

```
private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ILArray<float> data = ILSpecialData.waterfallf(25, 100);
    var ilmsc = new ILImageSCPlot(data);
    var ilp = new ILPlotCube { ilmsc };
    // this line has changed:
    ilPanel1.Scene.Add(ilp);
}
```

Personally, I like the option of using C# object initializers for such scene setup. It does also help to locate bugs in your code like the one above:

```
// Same result created by using C# object initializers: 
private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ILArray<float> data = ILSpecialData.waterfallf(25, 100);
    // whole  scene setup as one instruction: 
    ilPanel1.Scene.Add(new ILPlotCube {
        new ILImageSCPlot(data)
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This works fine. No Timeout. Nevertheless the Image is not shown correct. With waterfallf(25, 100) the range above 12-14 is white. If I resize the  form I see short for a moment the blue/green range. But then it is paint white.

Comment: And I try also to plot many elements: waterfallf(25, 1 000 000). This need much time at start and every refresh by resize the form. The intensity plot from Measurement Studio, National Instruments has a very better performance. The problem is: the control doesn't need to paint 1 Million columns - the screen has max 4k columns. The control should reduce the data to paint.